# Mongoose won't save user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

What am I doing wrong here? My database is connected but for some reason mongoose cannot save the user. I have tried practically everything but i can't figure it out. Is it possible that someone else can lend me a helping hand?

```
var express = require('express');
const Bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
var router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/User');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

//Sign up page GET
router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('signup');
});

//Sign up page POST
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try{
   req.body.password = Bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);

  const user = new User({
    firstName: req.body.firstname,
    lastName: req.body.lastname, 
    description: req.body.description,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  })

  const result = await user.save(); 

  res.send('User saved'); 
}
catch (error){
  res.status(500).send(error);
}
});

//Login page GET
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please tell what error comes from mongoose db ??

Comment: Can you show your model file?